# How to set 2 backgrounds to single ImageView in Android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi, I am writing an application where I need to give two different backgrounds to a single ImageView; but, I don't know how to do this.

In my case, I need to set an animation and background image to a single ImageView; but it's showing only the animation not the image background.

I have written the image background as the `ic_launcher` image, but it's not showing, only the animation is showing. I need to both to show at the same time using the same ImageView. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AnimationDrawable Tranninganimation3;
     ImageView unlockimg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Tranninganimation3 = new AnimationDrawable();
      Tranninganimation3.setOneShot(false);
       new playninzi3().onPreExecute();

       unlockimg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
      unlockimg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

       unlockimg.setBackgroundDrawable(Tranninganimation3);  
       unlockimg.post(new Starter3()); 
}
public class playninzi3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        try {


            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated000copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated002copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated004copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated006copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                             .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated008copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated010copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated012copy), 150);
            Tranninganimation3.addFrame(
                    getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.glow_animated014copy), 150);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
 class Starter3 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Tranninganimation3.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it easly using LayerDrawable and  ImageView.setImageDrawable

Comment: create LayerDrawable with two layers: one normal, static BitmapDrawable and second AnimationDrawable

Comment: so read its docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

Comment: hi thanks..i tried using layerdrawable its working.. Resources r = getResources();
           Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
           layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           layers[1] = Tranninganimation3;
           LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
           unlockimg.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);